# Counting number of lines in test classes

Tags: java, cloc

I'm  developing a tool that recognizes test classes and counts the number of lines in those classes. The tool will also count the lines of the business code and compare the both results, here is my code:

```
    for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        if (f.getName().endsWith(".java")) {

            System.out.println("File:" + f.getName());
            countFiles++;

            Scanner testScanner = new Scanner(f);
            while (testScanner.hasNextLine()) {

                String test = testScanner.nextLine();
                if (test.contains("org.junit") || test.contains("org.mockito")) {
                    System.out.println("this is a test class");
                    testCounter++;

                    break;
                }
            }
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(f);

            while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {

                count++;
```

counting the business code using (count++) is working perfectly, but counting the number of code in test classes is not working using (testCounter++) is returning the number of test classes rather than the number of lines in those classes! what can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Just try debugging it to see why the `if` statement is not being entered into.

Comment: Hi, actually there is nothing wrong with the if statement, the program is able to recognize the test classes alresy! But counting the lines inside them is not working!

Comment: unbreaking makes ( this is a test class) prints several times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are wanting to count the number of lines that contain either `org.junit or org.mockito`

then you want to do

```
       while (testScanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String test = testScanner.nextLine();
            if (test.contains("org.junit") || test.contains("org.mockito")) 
            {
                hasTestLines = true;
            }
            count++;
        }

        if (hasTestLines) {
             System.out.println(String.format ("there were %d lines in file %s which also had org.junit||org.mockito", 
                                    count, f.getName());
        }
        else {
             System.out.println(String.format ("there were %d lines in file %s which did NOT have org.junit||org.mockito", 
                                    count, f.getName());
       }
```

Comment: no actually not! I want to count the number of LINES IN each CLASS (the whole class) containing "org.mockito" or "org.junit" not

Comment: What does your comment mean?  See my edit, maybe this is what you want?

Comment: your solution is assuming that i want to count the number of lines that contains org.mockito or org.junit. But I actually want to count the number of lines in any class that has a line that may contain org.mockito or org.junit